# Parâmetros em Java

Tags: java

Ola, pessoal!

Estou com uma dúvida que, aparentemente, deve ser simples. Estou trabalhando em um projeto no qual possui vários métodos com parâmetros sendo especificados dessa forma, por exemplo: `(String... parametro)`

Aqui um código de exemplo

```
private void metodo(RowWrapper rowWrapper, Coluna... colunas) {}
```

O quê significa essa anotação? Alguém poderia me ajudar, por gentileza?

Answer (score 1):

Os três pontos no último parâmetro servem para chamar o método como se ele tivesse versões sobrecarregadas que aceitassem no final de sua lista de argumentos um número arbitrário de argumentos do tipo do parâmetro.

Por exemplo, digamos que você declarou o método: `public static void foo(String... strings)`. Os 3 pontos significam que você pode chamar o método tanto sem nenhuma string quanto como mais de uma, ou seja, todas as chamadas funcionariam para o método:

```java
foo();
foo("Olá mundo");
foo("1", "2", "3");
```

Comment: Tecnicamente falando não é uma sobrecarga, no sentido de criar um método diferente para cada combinação de parâmetros. Sobrecarregar métodos é uma coisa que é feita em tempo de implementação/compilação, nesse caso das reticências o número de argumentos é dinâmico e ocorre em tempo de execução. Na verdade Java resolve isso sem sobrecarga, transformando a lista de argumentos em um array e tratando como um array dentro da implementação do método.

Comment: Sim, vc está certo

Answer (score -2):

Vou dar um exemplo.

Class Nome

```
Private String dado;

Public Nome(){

}

Public void  metodo(String teste){
dado = teste;
}
```

class main( normalmente principal do programa )

```
Nome nm = new Nome();
String dadoProTest = "foi um teste";
nm.metodo(dadoProTeste);
```

Agora o dado da class Nome recebe  "foi um teste".

Esse comando a cima é um exemplo, o meu teste não pode ser acessado da class main pois ele está privado, então para atribuir dados a ele eu tenho q usar "metodo()" e esse valo passado dentro dele e usado para armazenar os dados, nesse exemplo foi criado uma String teste, e através dessa String eu passei um valor para o dado.
No outro eu passei ele com o nome de "dadoProTeste" mas o Java reconhece automaticamente que o "dadoProTeste" se trata do "teste" pois está na primeiro posição ( não é obrigatório colocar o mesmo nome ) ,  se tiver mais de 1 item, ex: método(String teste, String teste2), ai onde você for chamar você tem que seguir a ordem.

Comment: Olá. Você explicou a passagem de argumentos para o método mas quando tem as reticências no último argumento. Para entender veja a resposta linkada pelo hkotsubo.

Comment: Retificando: *mas não